select from DUAL python sqlalchemy ORM
I have a custom function on oracle database called create_identifier. It acccept a string and a column and concatenate the abbreviated form of the string to the column.
I am trying to get the python sqlalchemy orm equivalent of
select(select create_identifer("Name", u.name) from dual), u.id from User u

I am not sure how to get the oracle default table in python sqlalchemy orm.
I tried
select(select(func.create_identifier("Name", User.name) from dual), User.id) from User 

I also tried the SQLCompiler.default_from, it is not working I guess it is more compatible with raw sql than orm.

For future reference: Oracle Database 23ai queries don't need a FROM DUAL clause.

From the Using Textual SQL documentation:

Our last example really became a handful to type. Going from what one understands to be a textual SQL expression into a Python construct which groups components together in a programmatic style can be hard. That’s why SQLAlchemy lets you just use strings, for those cases when the SQL is already known and there isn’t a strong need for the statement to support dynamic features. The text() construct is used to compose a textual statement that is passed to the database mostly unchanged. Below, we create a text() object and execute it:
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import text
>>> s = text(
...     "SELECT users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title "
...     "FROM users, addresses "
...     "WHERE users.id = addresses.user_id "
...     "AND users.name BETWEEN :x AND :y "
...     "AND (addresses.email_address LIKE :e1 "
...     "OR addresses.email_address LIKE :e2)"
... )
>>> conn.execute(s, {"x": "m", "y": "z", "e1": "%@aol.com", "e2": "%@msn.com"}).fetchall()

SELECT users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title
FROM users, addresses
WHERE users.id = addresses.user_id AND users.name BETWEEN ? AND ? AND
(addresses.email_address LIKE ? OR addresses.email_address LIKE ?)
[...] ('m', 'z', '%@aol.com', '%@msn.com')
[(u'Wendy Williams, wendy@aol.com',)]


Your code would be:
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
sql = text("select create_identifer('Name', u.name), u.id from User u")
results = conn.execute(sql).fetchall()

Note: In Oracle, string literals use single ' quotes whereas double " quotes are for (quoted) identifiers. So 'Name' would be a string literal but "Name" would refer to a column called Name (with that exact capitalisation).
